# Are Class Activated Maps an example of backpropagated Explainable AI?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, convolution, explanatory-models

Class Activated Maps (NOT GradCAM) is listed in [van der Velden et al](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1361841522001177?ref=pdf_download&fr=RR-2&rr=786192f02c8c0d2e#bbib0158) as a back-propagation approach in table 1, but that is not actually true, is it?

CAM doesn't use back-propagation in the method, there is no gradient to be computed. Is it appropriate to still call it a backprop approach of Explainable AI?

Bas H.M. van der Velden, Hugo J. Kuijf, Kenneth G.A. Gilhuijs, Max A. Viergever,
[Explainable artificial intelligence (XAI) in deep learning-based medical image analysis](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.media.2022.102470.),
*Medical Image Analysis*,
Volume 79,
2022,
102470,
ISSN 1361-8415.